# How to prove that an integral over a generalised space is one minus the ratio of Fibonacci numbers?

Tags: calculus, integration, number-theory, proof-writing, fibonacci-numbers

Consider the following integral on the space $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{R}^+$, such that $\int_\Omega p(x)dx=\frac{F_{k+1}}{F_{k+2}}$,

$$\int_{\Omega}\frac{p(x)\left(1-\frac{F_{k+1}}{F_{k+2}}-\delta+\delta\frac{F_{k+1}}{F_{k+2}}\right)}{\delta-\delta\frac{F_{k+1}}{F_{k+2}}+\frac{F_{k+1}}{F_{k+2}}}dx,$$

where $\delta=\lim_{z\rightarrow\infty}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{-z\left(x-2n\right)^2}\right)$. Note that $F_k$ is the fibonacci number at $k$ (and we assume this to be constant). How would I go about proving that this integral is equivalent to $1-\frac{F_{k+1}}{F_{k+2}}=1-\int_{\Omega}p(x)dx$? Any help would be much appreciated.

**Sketch of proof:**

If we assume $\delta=0$, for all $x$ (even though it is a pulse at even integers),
$$\frac{1-F\left(k\right)}{F\left(k\right)}\int_{\Omega}p(x)dx=1-F(k),$$

where $F(k)=\frac{F_{k+1}}{F_{k+2}}$. However, this doesn't seem rigorous (i.e. why can we assume $\delta=0$ when integrating).

**Clarification on Delta function:**
This delta function is a pulse of magnitude $1$ at even integers, whereas the Dirac delta function has a pulse of $\infty$ at $x=0$:

[image: Delta function]

Comment: This seems very complicated. Where did this integral come up for you? Perhaps some expert might be able to see an easier way, given the context

Comment: Thanks for your response: the integral forms part of my research on dynamical systems (this is the simplest version of it, since it is meant to be generalised). I also posted on math overflow. The $\delta$ term is the only problem (without it the coefficient for $p(x)$ is constant). I calculated the integral numerically in MATLAB and it seems that $\delta$ should be treated as equivalent to $0$. I can't think of how to make this rigorous though.

Comment: I suppose I have to defer to Wolfram. Never mind - I'll leave it for the experts

Comment: @FShrike All good, your working was completely correct. It's just your last step (to get to the final solution) has a few intricacies.

Comment: Wait - @UNOwen, Wolfram says the limit is zero if $(x-2n)^2\ge0$. From what I can tell of your question, there are no complex variables here - the square is always positive, no?

Comment: Just greater than (i.e. $>$). At $n=2$, for example, $\delta=1$.

Comment: I'm embarrassing myself - I do know $\exp(0)=1$ - one last shot; I don't know measure theory, but isn't the measure of the set of points $x$ such that there is a term in the sum where $x-2n=0$, zero? Only the set of naturals satisfies that, and the set from which $x$ is chosen, the extended reals, is vastly larger than the set of naturals, as Cantor showed. Those impulses on the graph are infinitesimally negligible, no?

Comment: If it isn't, this is a good learning opportunity for me

Comment: Yes, they are infinitesimally small. So, borrowing some maths from measure theory might do it! I'll have a look at that and hopefully it's enough to prove the original statement. By the way, you aren't embarrassing yourself, I am always happy to talk through maths.

Comment: I share that tutor's feeling and thanks for the kindness, but I have certainly made mistakes I don't normally :) Good luck with the measures